# extract duplicate sub-char* from multiple char*

Tags: c++, char, concatenation

I have a `struct` whose constructor accepts a `char*` (as opposed to a `std::string`). I want to construct multiple instances of this class, with similar parameters:

```
struct X {
  char* x;
};

// usage

X xx = {"x.com/x"};

X xy = {"x.com/y"};

X xz = {"x.com/z"};
```

The parameters are a bit complex and the common sub-"string" is longer than just "x.com/", so extracting it would help make it more readable, but I'm not sure how:

```
const static char* domain = "x.com/";

X xx = {domain + "x"};

X xy = {domain + "y"};

X xz = {domain + "z"};
```

I've tried declaring `domain` as `std::string`, `char*`, `char[]`. I've also tried omitting and not omitting the `+`. I would like to avoid creating local vars or using `strcopy` as I imagine that would minimize the code readability gains by adding complexity to something that should ideally be ~3 short lines. Also, I got it to work by declaring `domain` as `std::string` and invoking `.c_str()`; e.g. `X xx = {(domain + "x").c_str()};`, but this too is hurting readability imo.

I imagine the likely answer is I have to live with repeating the sub-strings or use something that adds verbosity. But perhaps my C++ ignorance and lack of precise terminology means I missed something obvious when trying to search solutions.

Edit regarding modifying `X`:

I can't modify my struct `X` (it's some sort of dependency/utility) used in a lot of places in our codebase, nor is it always constructed with "x.com/" when used elsewhere.

Comment: FWIW `X xx = {(domain + "x").c_str()};` leaves you with a dangling pointer so it is definitely not what you want (it should also fail to compile because it violates const correctness).   An easy work around is to have `X` store a reference to the common part and then have a member variable that has the non common part.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware about the pointer issue. Regarding the suggestion, the struct X is used by many other places by the larger team. I can't modify it, nor is it always constructed with "x.com/" when used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

First off, assigning a string literal to a `char*` was deprecated in in C++03 and was removed from C++11.  `x` should be a `const char*` to be standard complaint.

Since you can't modify `X` you can use a little trick leverage the fact the string literals that are separated by nothing but white space get merged together during the compilation process.  That means if you have

```
"hello " "world"
```

the compiler will merge it into

```
"hello world"
```

Knowing that, you can leverage the preprocessor to define a symbol like

```
#define DOMAIN "x.com/"
```

and then you can use it to initialize your objects like

```
X xx = {DOMAIN "x"};

X xy = {DOMAIN "y"};

X xz = {DOMAIN "z"};
```

which gets resolved to

```
X xx = {"x.com/x"};

X xy = {"x.com/y"};

X xz = {"x.com/z"};
```

for you.